# Set TableView Width and Height in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How do I set the width and height of a TableView in Xamarin Forms? Setting `tableView.WidthRequest` isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

WidthRequest just describes an element's desired width during the next layout cycle.

A better explanation of WidthRequest [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849565/understanding-widthrequest)

[LayoutOptions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options/)  also effects `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`, default value is `HorizontalOptions.Fill` and `VerticalOptions.Fill` ,it will expand its parent view if we don't set value on it .

#### Solution 1

Put `TableView` into `Grid` and set `ColumnDefinitions`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TableView WidthRequest="100" >
    </TableView>
</Grid>
```

#### Solution 2

Set `LayoutOptions` from `Fill` to `Start`.

```
<TableView WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start">
```

Comment: Hi ,did it help or not?