# Frame too large even with HeightRequest = "1"

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I created a `Frame` with a Grid inside with a `Boxview` and an `Image`, but the Frame is still too big even though I entered `HeightRequest: "1"`.
How is it possible?

```
  <Frame
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=Constant,
        Constant=11}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=Constant,
        Constant=310}"
        CornerRadius="100"
        HeightRequest="1"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Graph_Clicked"/>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <Grid>
           <BoxView
                  Color="#404040"
                  CornerRadius="100"
                  Opacity="0.6"
                  Margin="-20"/>
           <Image               
                  Margin="-10"
                  Source="Chart.png"/> 
           </Grid>
    </Frame>
```

Comment: the Frame is expanding to fit its contents.

Comment: set `<Frame VerticalOptions="Start"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a Frame with a Grid inside with a Boxview and an Image, but the Frame is still too big even though I entered HeightRequest: "1"

According to Jason's opinion, the Frame is expanding to fit its contents. If you want to make frame smaller, you just change set **image HeightRequest and WidthRequest** samller, then Frame will become smaller.

```
<Frame
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            CornerRadius="100"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,
                                                              Constant=100}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,
                                                              Constant=0}">
            <Grid>
                <BoxView
                    CornerRadius="100"
                    Opacity="0.6"
                    Color="#404040" />
                <Image
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    Source="c11.png"
                    WidthRequest="50" />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin - (negative). And height and width are requested in Xamarin.Forms and not set actually. Set [vertical and horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61885533/8892050) options for controls. Then set the HeightRequest and WidthRequest. Should solve your issue.

```
<Frame
      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,  Constant=11}"
      RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,  Constant=310}"
      CornerRadius="100"
      HeightRequest="100"
      BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Graph_Clicked"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <BoxView
                  Color="#404040"
                  CornerRadius="10"
                  Opacity="0.6"/>
                <Image   
                  Source="Chart.png"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```